# From Matlab to Python: N point with Gaussian Distribution inside a rectangle

Tags: python, matlab

I wrote this code in Matlab and I am looking for equivalent code in Python. Can someone help?
The code is to generate N Points inside a rectangle of side LxL with Gaussian Distribution.
The code was obtained from this link: [gaussian_inside_rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363356/how-to-generate-random-points-inside-a-rectangle-with-gaussian-distribution)

```
function ans = randn_rect( N, sigma, L )
ans = zeros(0,2);
while size(ans,1) < N,
   pts = sigma * randn( ceil(1.25*(N-size(ans,1))), 2 );    
   pts = pts(all(abs(pts)<L/2,2),:);
   ans = [ ans ; pts ];
end
ans = ans(1:N,:);
```

Comment: Please fix your code. "enter code here" fragment is clearly alien :^)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understad your comment?

Comment: Your code is not valid MATLAB language. You probably failed to clear the "enter code here" phrase when inserting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to sample `N` 2-dimensional points from a [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)? Gladly, [scipy comes with that one built-in](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html#scipy.stats.truncnorm).

This generates a N*2 numpy array `points` with random points:

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import numpy as np

N = 1000
L = 5.0
mu = 4.0
sigma = 0.8

lower, upper = 0, L

X = truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)

points = np.reshape(X.rvs(2*N), (N, 2))
```

The code was adapted [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444710/1071311).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I run the code for N =10 and L = 100, I have obtaied these points: [[ 3.12334787  3.70831649]
 [ 3.58128416  5.73846664]
 [ 4.3797186   4.03120809]
 [ 5.30411406  4.4329382 ]
 [ 4.50553099  4.00487617]
 [ 2.77175744  4.44342638]
 [ 4.18085468  3.42912618]
 [ 3.64834852  3.32652222]
 [ 4.19270372  4.1313387 ]
 [ 4.65842432  2.40781954]]  all the values are arround 4 even if L is 100 ??

Comment: If you didn't change `mu`, then yes, your values should be centered around 4. The array you've posted looks good.

Comment: Then, I should set mu to 100

Comment: I mean that the values are not ditributed all over the area of 100x100. Points are all very close to point(4,4)

Comment: Why would they distributed all over the area? The distribution in the example has a standard deviation of 0.8. It appears that you don't really know what a normal (Gaussian) distribution is. You should read up on that first.