# Adjusting the mean and standard deviation of a list of random numbers?

Tags: python, random, mean, python-3.7, normal-distribution

I have to create a list of random numbers (with decimals) in the range between -3 and 3. The problem is that the list must have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. How can I adjust the mean and standard deviation parameters? Is there a function I can use?

I was already able to create a list of random numbers between -3 and 3.

```
import random


def lista_aleatorios(n):
    lista = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
        lista[i] = random.uniform(-3, 3)
    return lista

print("\nHow many numbers do you want?: ")
n = int(input())

print (lista_aleatorios(n))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean `a mean of 0`? Distribution mean value is different from sample mean value - if I start sampling from simple gaussian, N(0,1), no bounds, then even if distribution mean is 0, sampling mean would be different and would be closing on 0 when number of samples is going to infinity. Do you want distribution mean to be zero? Or you want sample mean (actually, sum) of any sampled sequence to be exactly zero all the time? Those two conditions are quite different

Answer (score 0):

The function `random.normalvariate(mu, sigma)` allows you to specify the mean and the stdev for normally distributed random variables.

Comment: Thank you! But how could I control the range from -3 to 3 by using this function? Greetings!

Comment: Also I notice that with either this function or with random.gauss(mu, sigma), the sd and the mean approximate the values that I indicate. Nevertheless, they are not exactly the ones that I established. Is there a way I can adjust this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.gauss`, then scale:

```
import numpy as np

from random import gauss

def bounded_normal(n, mean, std, lower_bound, upper_bound):

    # generate numbers between lower_bound and upper_bound

    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        while True:
            value = gauss(mean, std)
            if lower_bound < value < upper_bound:
                break

        result.append(value)

    # modify the mean and standard deviation

    actual_mean = np.mean(result)
    actual_std = np.std(result)
    mean_difference = mean - actual_mean
    std_difference = std / actual_std
    new_result = [(element + mean_difference) * std_difference for element in result]

    return new_result
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks mate!

Comment: 1. It is usually called truncated gaussian/truncated normal. 2. You just made two hard conditions on RVs generated - sum is equal to 0 and sum of squares equal to another fixed value. It is usually not what people means when they say mean is zero. 3. After shift and rescale before return you sometimes WILL get numbers out of bounds.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux what do you suggest, then?

Comment: If you want to stay with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution, then take a look at formulas there. Basically, you have distribution values (\mu, \sigma) which you don't know, and mean and stddev which you want to achieve. You assign mean expression from TN to desired mean, variance expression to desired stddev^2, two equations for two unknowns, there would be a solution. Fortunately, \mu is going to be 0 due to min/max being symmetric and desired mean 0. For \sigma there is going to be one nonlinear equation, which could be solved and then  (mu, sigma) to be sampled from

Comment: using this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441779/how-to-specify-upper-and-lower-limits-when-using-numpy-random-normal. I would expect \sigma to be a bit bigger than 1, but not by much. Basically, you're cutting tails of Gaussian which means high sigma samples are gone now - you have to compensate by slightly widening the distribution.

Comment: please also take a look at question I asked @Help, he should clarify what he/she wants wrt mean/stddev

Comment: @gmds Please take a look at the answer I provided - it follows comments pretty closely

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is quick way to solution (if you want to use truncated gaussian). Set boundaries and desired stddev. I assume mean is 0. Then quick-and-crude code to do binary search for distribution `sigma`, solving for non-linear root (`brentq()` should be used in production code). All formulas are taken from Wiki page on [Truncated Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution). It (sigma) shall be larger than desired stddev due to the fact, that truncation removes random values which contribute to large stddev. Then we do quick sampling test - and mean and stddev are close to desired values but never exactly equal to them. Code (Python-3.7, Anaconda, Win10 x64)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

def alpha(a, sigma):
    return a/sigma

def beta(b, sigma):
    return b/sigma

def xi(x, sigma):
    return x/sigma

def fi(xi):
    return 1.0/np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi) * np.exp(-0.5*xi*xi)

def Fi(x):
    return 0.5*(1.0 + erf(x/np.sqrt(2.0)))

def Z(al, be):
    return Fi(be) - Fi(al)

def Variance(sigma, a, b):
    al = alpha(a, sigma)
    be = beta(b, sigma)
    ZZ = Z(al, be)

    return sigma*sigma*(1.0 + (al*fi(al) - be*fi(be))/ZZ - ((fi(al)-fi(be))/ZZ)**2)

def stddev(sigma, a, b):
    return np.sqrt(Variance(sigma, a, b))

m = 0.0 # mean
s =  1.0 # this is what we want
a = -3.0 # left boundary
b =  3.0 # right boundary

#print(stddev(s , a, b))
#print(stddev(s + 0.1, a, b))

slo = 1.0
shi = 1.1

stdlo = stddev(slo, a, b)
stdhi = stddev(shi, a, b)

sigma = -1.0
while True: # binary search for sigma
    sme = (slo + shi) / 2.0
    stdme = stddev(sme, a, b)
    if stdme - s == 0.0:
        sigma = stdme
        break
    elif stdme - s < 0.0:
        slo = sme
    else:
        shi = sme

    if shi - slo < 0.0000001:
        sigma = (shi + slo) / 2.0
        break

print(sigma) # we got it, shall be slightly bigger than s, desired stddev

np.random.seed(73123457)

rvs = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc=m, scale=sigma, size=1000000) # quick sampling test

print(np.mean(rvs))
print(np.std(rvs))
```

For me it printed

```
sigma = 1.0153870105743408
mean = -0.000400729471992301
stddev = 1.0024267696681475
```

with different seed or sequence length you might get output like

```
1.0153870105743408
-0.00015923177289006116
0.9999974266369461
```