# How can I replace numbers in an array that fall above an upper bound or below a lower bound in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to randomly generate numbers from a distribution. The numbers that do not fall within two standard deviations of the mean I want to replace, so that in the end all of the numbers in the array fall within this range. This is the code that I have so far:

```
mean = 150
COV = 0.4
sd = COV*mean
upper_limit = mean + 2*sd
lower_limit = mean - 2*sd
capacity = np.random.normal(mean, sd, size = (1,96))
for x in capacity:
    while x > upper_limit:
        x = np.random.normal(mean, sd, size = 1)
    while x < lower_limit:
        x = np.random.normal(mean, sd, size = 1)
```

However, I get the error message `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
Can anyone help with how to fix this?

Comment: Is it that `capacity` is a matrix, so each `x` in `capacity` is a row, but you're treating it like an individual element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441779/how-to-specify-upper-and-lower-limits-when-using-numpy-random-normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't iterate through a `numpy` array to do something on each element of the array. The whole point of using `numpy` is to make this faster by never iterating.

To check all values in `capacity` which are greater than `upper_limit`, just do this:

```
capacity > upper_limit
```

Then, you can get the indices of those items this way:

```
too_high_indices = np.where(capacity > upper_limit)
```

Then, you can generate a new random array to assign to all such, e.g.

```
capacity[too_high_indices] = np.random.normal(mean, sd, size=len(too_high_indices))
```

In the end, you do this:

```
too_high_indices = np.where(capacity > upper_limit)
while np.any(too_high_indices):
    capacity[too_high_indices] = np.random.normal(
        mean, sd, size=len(too_high_indices))
    too_high_indices = np.where(capacity > upper_limit)
```

Then repeat for the lower limit.

This way, it will be relatively fast even if the size grows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the `size` parameter from `(1, 96)` to `96`. Because here your `x` has shape `(96,)` so is an array and thus not comparable to a single float value.

Comment: just validate my answer then plz :)
Glad it helped

Comment: I just realized that although changing the size allowed the code to run, it did not replace any values outside of two standard deviations away

Answer (score 0):

```
# print(capacity)
# changed = set([])
for i in range( len(capacity[0]) ):
    while capacity[0][i] > upper_limit or capacity[0][i] < lower_limit:
        capacity[0][i] = np.random.normal(mean, sd, size = 1)[0]
        # changed.add(i)
# print(capacity)
# print(changed)
```