# truncnorm generates values below lower boundary

Tags: python, random

I want to generate normal distributed values and have found this post:
[How to specify upper and lower limits when using numpy.random.normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441779/how-to-specify-upper-and-lower-limits-when-using-numpy-random-normal)
However when I run the following code I get negative values below the lower limit as well

```
seed = 1
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

lower = 100_000
mean =  600_000_000
sigma = 700_000_000
nrows = 2000
upper = 10000000000


series = pd.Series(stats.truncnorm(
                    (lower - mean) / sigma,
                    (upper - mean) / sigma,
                    loc=mean,
                    scale=sigma,
                )
                .rvs(size=nrows)
                .astype(int))
series.hist()
```

[image]

What can I do to only get values above the lower limit?

Comment: Your code looks alright. I don't get any values below the lower limit.

Comment: that's strange, I have no idea why we could have different results, I added a seed, but I still get the same histogram

Comment: so I always get -2147483648 as the negative number on my local pc. I tried in colab and there I also had no issues

Comment: Try scaling your parameters down by an order of magnitude and run again. My only guess is that you are overflowing somewhere..

Comment: okay so I tested, on colab it gives me correctly 2257122278 on my local pc it converts it to -2147483648. It would be great if I could keep the magnitude

Comment: I just found out, that it is the .astype(int) conversion that generates the error

Comment: so I replaced it with .astype(np.int64) and it works now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved, the problem was with the .astype(int) conversion, with .astype(np.int64) it works just fine now